# Why weighted importance sampling is a biased estimator?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, sampling, monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator

By simple math, we can have
$$
E_P[f(X)] = \sum_X f(x)p(x) = \sum_X f(x)\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}q(x) = E_Q[f(X)\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}],
$$
which can be approximated by Monte Carlo sampling in two ways.

**1. Normal (ordinary) importance sampling:**
Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be i.i.d. samples from $Q(X)$, and $\mu_1$ the resulted estimator.
$$
\mu_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n f(X_i)\frac{P(X_i)}{Q(X_i)}
$$
Throughout the rest of this post, we also denote $w(x) = p(x)/q(x)$ as the importance weight. Therefore, the above estimator can also be written as
$$
\mu_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n w(X_i)f(X_i)
$$
One can prove that $\mu_1$ is an unbiased estimator by showing
$$
E_Q[\mu_1] = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n E_Q[f(X_i)\frac{P(X_i)}{Q(X_i)}]
= \frac{1}{n} \sum^n E_P[f(X)] =  E_P[f(X)]
$$

**2. Weighted importance sampling**: However, sometimes we do not know exactly $P(X)$ up to the normalizing constant, i.e. we know $g(x)$ instead, s.t. $p(x) = g(x)/Z$. This is more useful in the continuous case as $Z$ will be the integral constant, but we here take the discrete case for example. The importance weight is now revised to $w'(x) = g(x)/q(x)$, and consequently so will be the estimator
$$
\mu_2 = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum^n w'(X_i)f(X_i)}{\frac{1}{n} \sum^n w'(X_i)}
$$
One can show this estimator is consistent by showing that
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum^n w'(X_i)f(X_i)}{\frac{1}{n} \sum^n w'(X_i)}
& = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum^n w'(X_i)f(X_i)}
{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum^n w'(X_i)} \\
& = \frac{\sum_X g(x)/q(x) f(x) q(x)}
{\sum_X g(x)/q(x) q(x)} \\
& = \frac{ZE_P[f(X)]}{Z} = E_P[f(X)]
\end{split}
$$
And a fun fact is that $\frac{1}{n} \sum^n w'(X_i)$ is actually also an unbiased estimator of the normalizing constant $Z$, i.e. an integral estimate.

***Nevertheless, can anyone show that $\mu_2$ is a biased estimator (as it is claimed to be a trade-off between bias and variance), since I cannot find any formal proof and failed to prove it on my own?***

---

Some references:

1. [The original paper on weighted importance sampling](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/technometrics/90-00/vol-37-02/v3702185.pdf), where I did not find the proof showing the estimator is unbiased.
2. [A possibly related answer by Xi'an](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/244502/362671), but seems he is jumping over a few steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I was ["jumping over a few steps"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/244502/362671), the argument seems simple enough to me: if $N$ and $D$ are (not necessarily independent) random variables such that $\mathbb E[N]=\nu$ and $\mathbb E[D]=\delta$ then
$$\mathbb E[1/D]\ne \frac1\delta\quad\text{and}\quad\mathbb E[N/D]\ne\frac\nu\delta$$
except in highly specialised circumstances. For once thing, the lhs [may be undefined](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/299765/7224) as, e.g., when $D$ is a Normal variate (a fact linked with the [Cauchy variate having no mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100161/7224)). For another, assuming $D>0$, the inequality is a consequence of Jensen's inequality: since the mapping $\iota: x\mapsto 1/x$ is strictly convex, $\mathbb E[\iota(D)]>\iota(\mathbb E[D])$.

For a mathematical study of the self- (or auto-) normalised importance sampling estimator, see [Agapiou et al.  (2014).](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06196.pdf)

Comment: Hi Professor, glad you saw this post :-) I can understand the Jensen's inequality in your original post and here. However, my question is : N and D in our case are weighted samples and corresponding weights respectively, so they are actually one (jointly distributed) random variable (up to different evaluation functions). Therefore, instead of E[N/D], our case is pretty much like E[f(X)/g(X)], where E[f(X)] = \nu and E[g(X)] = \delta, and the bias of WIS seems to be provably O(1/n) (I saw this somewhere else but unfortunately forgot the source). Could you please add some comments, thank you!

Comment: Similarly$$\mathbb E[f(X)/g(X)]\ne\mathbb E[f(X)]\big/\mathbb E[g(X)]$$in most cases, hence the bias. This bias naturally decreases with the number $n$ of Monte Carlo simulations since the estimator is convergent.

Comment: Dear Professor, sorry to bother you again. I can understand that the expectation of the ratio does not necessarily equal to the ratio of the expectations. But I am really eager to figure out the gap (bias) in this special case of auto normalized importance sampling. [con't]

Comment: [con't] So I read this [2014 paper] on my own and looked into the proof detail. The proof in appendix 6.3 for Theorem 2.1 shall resolve my confusion. However, I got stuck in inequalities in the first paragraph of page 44. I can understand what leads to it and what follows but just cannot get this very part: (1) in the second inequality why the second abs expectation becomes a probability, and (2) how to get the third inequality, it looks like something of the variance of the sample distribution? Could you please kindly give me some hint?